# Ajax form validation in php

Tags: php, ajax

Im trying to create ajax from with php validation, let explain with screenshot. while validating form im getting all error in same place…

[image: from]

what im trying to get is individual validation for field like below

[image: form1]

And after form is submitted i want display success message at the top of form but im getting success message on all field

[image]

html form data (index.php)

```
<form id="first_form" method="POST" action="form.php">
<p class="form-message"></p>
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name:">
    <p class="form-message"></p>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="tex" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email:">
    <p class="form-message"></p>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone:">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address:">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject:">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="services" name="services" placeholder="Services:">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Leave Your Message..."></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#first_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
        name     = $("#name").val();
        email    = $("#email").val();
        phone    = $("#phone").val();
        address  = $("#address").val();
        subject  = $("#subject").val();
        services = $("#services").val();
        message  = $("#message").val();
        submit   = $("#submit").val();

        $(".form-message").load("form.php", {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            address: address,
            subject: subject,
            services: services,
            message: message,
            submit: 'submitted'
        });

});
```

});

form.php data

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailTo = "hello@develoweb.com";
$headers = "From: ".$email;
$txt = "You have received a message from ".$name.
    ".\n\n".$message;

$errorEmptyname = false;
$errorEmptyemail = false;
$errorEmptymessage = false;
$errorEmail = false;

if (empty($name)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Name Field cannot be empty</span> ";
    //$errorEmptyName = true;
}  

if (empty($email)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Email Field cannot be empty</span>";
    //$errorEmptyemail = true;
}    

if (empty($message)) {
    //$errorEmptymessage = true;
}
elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>
    Write a valid e-mail addres </span>";
    $errorEmail = true;
}
else {
    echo "<span class='form-success'>
    Thank you for your message!<br>
    I'll get back to you as soon as I can.</span>";
    
    mail($mailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
}
else{
    echo "There was an error!";
}
```

what i have understand, im not getting individual validation error in individual field bcz class is same, how can i append error to related fields

i havent used js validation bcz i want to some validation for spammer to prevent spam mail and as we know while viewing source code we can easily view code for validation too, so pefer validation in php

Comment: You could create an array to store errors in PHP, populated with form element name as key and error as the value - at the end of processing POST request send back the json encoded errors array and iterate through that to mark each field that has error

Comment: Hi, in addition to what @ProfessorAbronsius suggested, another way to go about this is to place a die; after the echo statement, in that way the code below will not run.

Comment: @EmekaOkafor but die command will kill all code after it but i want  content even after unsuccessful

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius your idea solve my issue but i can run condition where even if condition does meet i want to display successful message with hidden field how can implement this with ajax , this code works fine form submit

Comment: i dont want submit form if hidden field value is change but want display message successful message.
`$response = [];
 
 if(empty($errors))
 {
  $response['success_message'] = "Thank you for your message!<br>I'll get back to you as soon as I can.";
 }elseif($post['spam'] !== $floor){
  $response['success_message'] = "Thank you for your message!<br>I'll get back to you as soon as I can.";
 }
 else
 {
  foreach($errors as $key=>$value)
  {
   $response[$key.'_error'] = $value;
  }
 }
 echo json_encode($response);`